# Login automatically after signing in with Google Login

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

I have successfully integrated the *Sign in with Google* feature in an application. My question is, how do I store this information so the user can skip the login screen next time and go straight into the application without needing to Sign in again?

This is the code so far:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @Bind(R.id.googleSignIn)SignInButton googleSignIn;
    GoogleSignInOptions options;
    GoogleApiClient client;

    private static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        /** CONFIGURE THE GOOGLE SIGN IN OPTIONS **/
        options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile().build();
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();

        /** CONFIGURE THE SIGN IN BUTTON **/
        googleSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        googleSignIn.setScopes(options.getScopeArray());
        googleSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent signIn = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(client);
                startActivityForResult(signIn, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN && resultCode == RESULT_OK)   {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            String name = account.getDisplayName();
            Log.e("DISPLAY NAME", name);
            String email = account.getEmail();
            Log.e("USER EMAIL", email);
            String profile = String.valueOf(account.getPhotoUrl());
            Log.e("USER PROFILE", profile);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
}
```

I haven't found anything about *persisting* the Google Login when the user closes the app and opens it anytime later. Most tutorials mostly deal with the integration part which I already have working. A bunch of questions on SO are entirely different too. Nothing in this context.

Would I need to store the account data in say `SharedPreferences`? Or does the SDK handle that part all by itself.

I appreciate any help you folks can offer.

P.S.: This question is different from my previous question about creating a record in my MySQL database.

Comment: use a shared preference; and store some boolean and later once u get on to login screen u can check the flag in pref; and perform appropriate action :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, turned out, it was simpler than what was suggested in the two answers. Since both the answers didn't really offer anything substantial other than suggestions of sorts, I searched some more. This led to finding this [Google+ Developers Live YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2fOn8jwVcc). And in the description of this video was a link to *[Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start)* link which led further to this https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git.

The Quick Start sample on the GitHub page demonstrated precisely what I was looking for.

I am posting an updated version of the code posted in the OP for other users who might stumble on this question and save them some time hopefully.

Beside the slight structural changes, the most important addition was of the `onStart()` which uses `OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult>` that silently determines if an active session of the previously signed in account exists in which case, it will sign in automatically. If the session has expired, it basically create a new session without any additional code. The `if...else` block in the `onStart()` is the key for the two possibilities.

```
public class NewLogin extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @OnClick(R.id.googleSignIn) public void GoogleLogin()   {
        Intent signIn = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(client);
        startActivityForResult(signIn, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }
    GoogleSignInOptions options;
    GoogleApiClient client;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        /** CONFIGURE THE GOOGLE SIGN IN OPTIONS **/
        options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile().build();
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(client);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
            Log.e("CACHE STATUS", "Got cached sign-in");
        } else {
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // [START handleSignInResult]
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d("handleSignInResult:", String.valueOf(result.isSuccess()));
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), acct.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String name = acct.getDisplayName();
            Log.e("DISPLAY NAME", name);
            String email = acct.getEmail();
            Log.e("USER EMAIL", email);
            String profile = String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl());
            Log.e("USER PROFILE", profile);
            Log.e("ID", acct.getId());
        }
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store data like profile name, profile picture url etc.
When user click on Logout button, remove these data from `SharedPreferences` and also logout user from Google.
Use this code to logout from Google.

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
     new ResultCallback<Status>() {
         @Override
         public void onResult(Status status) {

         }
     }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better than using `SharedPreferences` I would recommend using the integrated accounts system. Check the documentation for [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

Implementing it this way is a bit harder than just using `SharedPreferences` but once you understand it is quite simple. You can find several tutorials online [like this one](https://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2)

`SharedPreferences` is for storing precisaly that, preferences about the app (like date or time format). What you want to do is store the account info